# ActiveRecord error when running rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-postgresql

When I launch rails console and want to test a model template I just created, rails console failed to create my new model instance.

```
yellow:maw thierry$ rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 17717
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.0)
>> Account.create(name: "John Doe", email: "john.doe@example.com", password: "1234ABCD", password_confirmation: "1234ABCD")
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "accounts" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"accounts"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
                     c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
                FROM pg_attribute a
                LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
                LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"accounts"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum

    from (irb):1
>>
```

But, with "rails db", executing the ActiveRecord SQL request in the same environment (here, development) give me this output :

```
yellow:maw thierry$ rails db
psql (9.6.2)
Type "help" for help.

maw_development=> SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
maw_development->                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
maw_development->                      c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
maw_development->                 FROM pg_attribute a
maw_development->                 LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
maw_development->                 LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
maw_development->                 LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
maw_development->                WHERE a.attrelid = '"accounts"'::regclass
maw_development->                  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
maw_development->                ORDER BY a.attnum;
     attname     |         format_type         |             pg_get_expr              | attnotnull | atttypid | atttypmod | collname | comment 
-----------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+----------+-----------+----------+---------
 id              | bigint                      | nextval('accounts_id_seq'::regclass) | t          |       20 |        -1 |          | 
 name            | character varying           |                                      | f          |     1043 |        -1 |          | 
 email           | character varying           |                                      | f          |     1043 |        -1 |          | 
 created_at      | timestamp without time zone |                                      | t          |     1114 |        -1 |          | 
 updated_at      | timestamp without time zone |                                      | t          |     1114 |        -1 |          | 
 password_digest | character varying           |                                      | f          |     1043 |        -1 |          | 
(6 rows)

maw_development=> SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
                     c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
                FROM pg_attribute a
                LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
                LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
               WHERE a.attrelid = 'accounts'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum;
     attname     |         format_type         |             pg_get_expr              | attnotnull | atttypid | atttypmod | collname | comment 
-----------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------+----------+-----------+----------+---------
 id              | bigint                      | nextval('accounts_id_seq'::regclass) | t          |       20 |        -1 |          | 
 name            | character varying           |                                      | f          |     1043 |        -1 |          | 
 email           | character varying           |                                      | f          |     1043 |        -1 |          | 
 created_at      | timestamp without time zone |                                      | t          |     1114 |        -1 |          | 
 updated_at      | timestamp without time zone |                                      | t          |     1114 |        -1 |          | 
 password_digest | character varying           |                                      | f          |     1043 |        -1 |          | 
(6 rows)

maw_development=>
```

All migrations have already been applied :

```
yellow:maw thierry$ rake db:migrate:status

database: maw_development

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20170505175757  Create enterprises
   up     20170507120815  Create accounts
   up     20170507170408  Add index to users email
   up     20170507172846  Add password digest to users

yellow:maw thierry$
```

Like you will able to see, I've executed two times the request :

- One by letting the single + double quote in the generated model name.
- One with only single quotes.

Does anybody encountered this error ? And how do you solved it ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Context:**

- Rails 5.1.0
- On macOS Sierra
- Using Rbenv.
- With Ruby 2.4.1p111.
- PG adapter : 0.20.0

In models directory :

```
yellow:maw thierry$ ls -al app/models/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   6 thierry  staff  204  7 mai 14:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 thierry  staff  340  5 mai 16:23 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 thierry  staff  531  8 mai 12:44 account.rb
-rw-r--r--   1 thierry  staff   78  5 mai 16:23 application_record.rb
drwxr-xr-x   3 thierry  staff  102  5 mai 16:23 concerns
-rw-r--r--@  1 thierry  staff  161  7 mai 18:41 enterprise.rb
yellow:maw thierry$
```

Content of account.rb:

```
yellow:maw thierry$ cat app/models/account.rb 
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 250 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password
  #This validation must be put after has_secure_password in order for the password field to be defined.
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
yellow:maw thierry$
```

Comment: Did you restart the rails console?

Comment: Yes, many times.

Comment: Could it be an issue with `spring`?

Comment: It was ! Thanks @Iceman

Comment: Not the first time spring is causing difficulties, I quit using it sadly for reasons like this.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Iceman suggested in his comment, it was "spring related". So, I've :

- stop rails console.
- stop spring with "spring stop".
- checked that spring was really stop with "ps aux | grep spring" and it was.
- and finally restarted "rails console".

And the result is :

```
yellow:maw thierry$ rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 22940
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.0)
>> Account.create(name: "John Doe", email: "john.doe@example.com", password: "1234ABCD", password_confirmation: "1234ABCD")
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Account Exists (61.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE LOWER("accounts"."email") = LOWER($1) LIMIT $2  [["email", "john.doe@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "accounts" ("name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "John Doe"], ["email", "john.doe@example.com"], ["created_at", "2017-05-09 08:14:29.093633"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-09 08:14:29.093633"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$3rCS7ynWP1r8VuPRDyQmOe0Czpm6ingOX16I6./s9a5TjUxnkPSzu"]]
   (40.5ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Account id: 1, name: "John Doe", email: "john.doe@example.com", created_at: "2017-05-09 08:14:29", updated_at: "2017-05-09 08:14:29", password_digest: "$2a$10$3rCS7ynWP1r8VuPRDyQmOe0Czpm6ingOX16I6./s9a5...">
>>
```